# Cannot resolve error in intellij and spark 2.2

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to Query Temptable in spark
below is my code.

```
package batch
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Encoders, SQLContext, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  object BatchJob {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val spark = SparkSession.builder
        .master("local")
        .appName("Fraud Detector")
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
        .enableHiveSupport
        .getOrCreate()

      import spark.implicits._

      val financesDF = spark.read.json("C:/spark/spark/question/data.json")
      financesDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")


      val ds = sqlContext.sql(
        """
          |SELECT *
          |FROM people
""".stripMargin)
```

My POM file looks like as below.

```
<properties>
<spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.version}</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The Error i am getting as:
**Error:(30, 16) not found: value sqlContext
val ds = sqlContext.sql(**

Kindly help me, if i am missing something.
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skKQx.png)

Comment: you don't have a spark variable, you have `sc`

Comment: @SašaZejnilović: Thanks .......my bad.... missed to add it.

Comment: @SašaZejnilović: Many Thanks Sir..... may you please help me why i am getting error as cannot resolve createOrReplaceTempView when try to create tempview from dataframe. financesDF.createOrReplaceTempView("myTempView")

Comment: `financesDF` is `Unit`, remove that `.show()`

Comment: @SašaZejnilović: Thanks a lot Sir... Learn something new

Comment: @SašaZejnilović: May i ask 1 last question please

Comment: @SašaZejnilović: Even after import import org.apache.spark.sql._, i am getting error as val ds = sqlContext.sql(
        """
          |SELECT *
          |FROM people  , kindly share your suggestion

Comment: try `spark.sqlContext`